# Can't scroll over ion-items, scroll lock

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm creating a user interface for my new app but I discovered a problem. I use ion-items as buttons and together they all make one big button block. My problem is I still have more content below but the user is unable to scroll when swiping over the buttons. So they are stuck unless they swipe on the very right or left where the buttons stop, which is hard to figure out and annoying. How do I allow scrolling over these buttons. Thanks.

**Update**

I found this to be a problem for other people as well, maybe it's a glitch in ionic itself?

Html Code:

```
<ion-view id="page9">
<ion-nav-title>
    <span class="blue">{{title}}</span>
</ion-nav-title>


  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">

<div class="scroll padding">

<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>



<div class="list card" id="fBLA-card24" data-componentid="card24" data-tap-disabled="true">

<a ng-click="membersPage()"><ion-item class="item-icon-left item" id="fBLA-list-item8" data-componentid="list-item8" data-tap-disabled="true">
<i class="icon ion-android-people">

</i>Members</ion-item></a>
<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>
<a ng-click="eventsPage()"><ion-item class="item-icon-left item" id="fBLA-list-item10" data-componentid="list-item10" data-tap-disabled="true"><i class="icon ion-ios-people">
</i>Events</ion-item></a>

<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>
<a ng-click="scanAndCheck()"><ion-item class="item-icon-left item" id="fBLA-list-item9" data-componentid="list-item9" data-tap-disabled="true">
<i class="icon ion-android-checkbox">

</i>Scan and Check</ion-item></a>
<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>
<a ng-click = "scanBarcode()"><ion-item class="item-icon-left item" id="fBLA-list-item11" data-componentid="list-item11" data-tap-disabled="true">
<i class="icon ion-qr-scanner"></i>Scan new members</ion-item></a>
<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>

<a ng-click = "payment()"><ion-item class="item-icon-left item" id="fBLA-list-item11" data-componentid="list-item11" data-tap-disabled="true">
<i class="icon ion-cash"></i>Members Payment</ion-item></a>
<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>

<a ng-click = "settings()"><ion-item class="item-icon-left item" id="fBLA-list-item11" data-componentid="list-item11" data-tap-disabled="true">
<i class="icon ion-android-settings"></i>Club Settings</ion-item></a>
<div class="spacer" style="height: 20px;"></div>

</div>
<button id="fBLA-button9" class="button button-assertive  button-block icon-left ion-android-delete" data-componentid="button9" ng-click="deleteClub()" data-tap-disabled="true">Delete Club
</button>
<div class="vcenter">Need to scan a large amount of people? Use the Access Code in Settings.</div>
</div>




  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image: User can only scroll on the very sides, need the user to be able to scroll on the buttons]

Comment: did you tried an overflow:hidden on sections ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? @AndreiTodorut

Comment: @DanielKBoyer When pressing a button, it prevents a scroll action. So a list of buttons doesnt allow you to scroll because when you press on the button and swipe up, instead of responding to the swipe, it is listening to how long you press the button. This makes it currently impossible to have a list of ion-item buttons without a bad user experience.